# How to handle relative pathing across multiple modules and stylesheets?

Tags: javascript, java, html, web, relative-path

Backstory: I'm serving my application from deep inside a separate but independent application for the purpose of integrating with that application's feature set.

One of the "features" that it offers is to allow access to the "extension" you are creating via a url path like: http://localhost/path/to/my/extension

So all of my CSS and JS need to be using /path/to/my/extension as the base URL whenever using things like `background-image: url(/my/fancy/img.svg)` as well as module paths like `/jspm_modules/repo/some_system_module@v1.js`.

Any requests that actually hit the proper path like: `/path/to/my/extension/some/thing` I'm able to handle like I want because I can control the request and point it at the right resource server-side.

What I'm struggling with is what to do about things like es6-module-loader and embedded style sheets that use the relative pathing format.

Sorry if my question is hard to understand, I'm not quite sure how to even ask it right as I haven't had to face this issue before. Feel free to edit, leave comments asking for clarification, etc. I encourage it as I need to learn since this seems like it could be (might be?) fairly common.

[image: Some failure messages since the resources are not pointed to my extension path]

Comment: I'm using what amounts to a Java servlet to handle the requests at ```/path/to/my/extension```.